# RabbitMQ Bundle : One queue & multiple workers

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm currently trying to use RabbitMQ ( with the excellent RabbitMQBundle ) to process a lot of async work.

The goal is to have one queue to publish messages of the same type and to have X workers on multiple servers to peek messages in the same time.

Each worker have to peek one message, do the job then peek another message etc..

Here my conf :

```
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
connections:
    default:
        host:     'localhost'
        port:     5672
        user:     'myuser'
        password: 'mypassword'
        vhost:    '/'
        lazy:     false
producers:
    generate_report:
        connection:       default
        exchange_options: { name: 'gen_report', type: fanout }
consumers:
    generate_report:
        connection:       default
        exchange_options: { name: 'gen_report', type: fanout }
        queue_options:    { name: 'gen_report' }
        callback:         generator.report.consumer
```

In my consumer, i have an entry in a logfile and a sleep of 120 seconds.

I started **php app/console rabbitmq:consumer generate_report** like 10 times, but when i look my log file i have only message each 120 and the goal is to have 10 !

I've also tried to set my queue as topic or direct with the same results.

I don't understand what i'm doing wrong :'(

Thanks in advance

Kind regards

Comment: Can you please further explain the problem. I don't understand what you have and what you want?

Comment: I want to have for example 2 workers generating my reports simultaneously using the same queue.
At the moment, when i start 2 worker only one ( the first ) is working. The second do nothing except when i shutdown the first

Comment: Aha, now I get it. The workers seem to be locking each other out. Do you have any idea what kind of resources they could be competing on? Output files could (and should) have file-locks on them, database tables (for MyISAM) and rows (for InnoDB) have locks. It's something the first worker does that prevents the second worker from doing anything

Comment: Waht about to set prefetch count to 1?

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same issue. What you can do is set the number of messages fetched to 1.

`$channel->basic_qos(null, 1, null);`

http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-php.html , see Fair dispatch section.